# R: How to rescale my matrix by column

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix of disease states `states0CommercialA`, where the columns are states (i.e., "no disease", "disease", "dead") and the rows are model cycles (i.e., 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.).

I'm trying to multiply this by a vector of costs `commercialMedExp`, wherein each cost corresponds to a disease state. I've attempted the following:

```
commercialMedExp * states0CommercialA
```

but it appears as though the multiplication is occurring across columns instead of across rows. Could someone help me with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
commercialMedExp0A <- t(apply(states0CommercialA, 1, function(x){ x * commercialMedExp}))
```

should work so long as the number of columns in `states0CommericialA` is the same length as `commercialMedExp`.  If it is not you would have to subset the data. For example, if the disease states are in columns 13 through 18

```
    commercialMedExp0A <- t(apply(states0CommercialA[,c(13:18)], 1, function(x){ x * commercialMedExp}))
```

Answer (score 2):

Column / Row rescaling is a common operation in matrix computation. You are looking for column rescaling, but I will offer solutions to both.

---

**Row rescaling**

```
A <- matrix(1:20, nrow = 5); x <- 1:5
## Any method below is much more efficient than `diag(x) %*% A`

## method 1: recycling
A * x

## method 2: `sweep()`
sweep(A, 1L, x, "*")
```

**Column rescaling**

```
A <- matrix(1:20, nrow = 5); y <- 1:4
## Any below method is much more efficient than `A %*% diag(y)`

## method 1: transpose + row rescaling
t(y * t(A))

## method 2: `sweep()`
sweep(A, 2L, y, "*")

## method 3: pairwise multiplication
A * rep(y, each = nrow(A))
```

---

**What you can do**

```
states0CommercialA * rep(commercialMedExp, each = nrow(states0CommercialA))
```