# how to let a matrix minus vector by row rather than by column

Tags: r

I want to get the data that each column minus its mean.
First I count the mean of each column 
There is my data bellow called m

```
         angel distance
     [1,]   1.3     0.43
     [2,]   4.0     0.84
     [3,]   2.7     0.58
     [4,]   2.2     0.58
     [5,]   3.6     0.70
     [6,]   4.9     1.00
     [7,]   0.9     0.27
     [8,]   1.1     0.29
     [9,]   3.1     0.63

> mean<-apply(m,2,FUN=mean)

        angel  distance 
    2.6444444 0.5911111 

> m-mean
        angel    distance
1 -1.34444444 -0.16111111
2  3.40888889 -1.80444444
3  0.05555556 -0.01111111
4  1.60888889 -2.06444444
5  0.95555556  0.10888889
6  4.30888889 -1.64444444
7 -1.74444444 -0.32111111
8  0.50888889 -2.35444444
9  0.45555556  0.03888889
```

So the final answer is got through minus mean by column.
I want it minus by each row. How can I get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's use `colMeans(m)` to get column means of matrix `m`. Then we use `sweep`:

```
sweep(m, 2, colMeans(m))
```

where `2` specifies margin (we want column-wise operation, and in 2D index, the second index is for column). By default, `sweep` performs `FUN = "-"`, so in above we are subtracting column means from the matrix, i.e., centring the matrix.

Similarly if we want to subtract row means from all rows, we can use:

```
sweep(m, 1, rowMeans(m))
```

You can set `FUN` argument to other functions, too. Another common use of `sweep` is for column / row rescaling, where you can read [How to rescale my matrix by column or row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38982077/4891738) for more.

---

Function `scale` mentioned by the other answer is used **only** for column-wise operation. A common use is to standardised all matrix columns. We can set `scale = FALSE` to perform column centring only.

`scale` is just a wrapper function of `sweep` which you can verify by inspecting the source code of `sweep.default`:

```
if (center) {
            center <- colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE)
            x <- sweep(x, 2L, center, check.margin = FALSE)
        }

if (scale) {
     scale <- apply(x, 2L, f)
        x <- sweep(x, 2L, scale, "/", check.margin = FALSE)
        }
```

Read `?sweep`, `?scale`, `?colMeans` for more on those functions.

Comment: Thank you very much. It provide more details for me. I am appreciated that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same by this (z-score normalization without scaling):

```
scale(df, scale=FALSE)

    angel    distance
[1,] -1.34444444 -0.16111111
[2,]  1.35555556  0.24888889
[3,]  0.05555556 -0.01111111
[4,] -0.44444444 -0.01111111
[5,]  0.95555556  0.10888889
[6,]  2.25555556  0.40888889
[7,] -1.74444444 -0.32111111
[8,] -1.54444444 -0.30111111
[9,]  0.45555556  0.03888889
```

Comment: Wow, it's more useful. Thanks for your help.